# Unit of Work through tiers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-of-work, n-tier-architecture

I'm refactoring an existing MVC.Net application to include the unit of work pattern to make data management a bit more obvious and straight forward.

The application is currently split into

1. Presentation/UI (MVC Controllers delivering views OR JsonResults for AngularJS)
2. Business Logic (Containing well... business logic)
3. DAL (Repositories and EF)

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how I need to be structuring dependency injection and UoW passing to keep things sensible and testable.

I'm anticipating something like the following to be an example:

```
public class SomeMVCController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStoreFrontLogic _storeFrontLogic;

    public SomeMVCController(IStoreFrontLogic storeFrontLogic)
    {
        _storeFrontLogic = storeFrontLogic;

        var uow = new UnitOfWork(User);
        _storeFrontLogic.UnitOfWork = uow;
    }

    public ActionResult SomeRequest()
    {
        var myViewModel = _storeFrontLogic.OffersForUser();
        return View(myViewModel);
    }
}

public class StoreFrontLogic : IStoreFrontLogic
{
    public UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public OffersModel OffersForUser()
    {
        //some logic taking into account the current user in the uow
        var prevOrders = unitOfWork.OrdersRepo.GetUsersOrders();

        // special offers logic

        return specialOffers;
    }
}
```

Does this seem sensible?
I'm not too keen on the requirement to manually push the uow into my logic classes whenever they're required. Is there a more sensible way?

Comment: You might want to restructure this to see if you can do a concrete question about design patterns. As it stands there can't really be a "correct" answer to this. Another possibility is to implement a prototype and post it on codreview.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

As I said above, this is hard to answer without a specific question or specific domain model but I'll give it a shot.

My understanding of such things is focused pretty heavily through a Domain Driven Design lens.

First of, you should read this series of papers on [effective aggregate design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/). The fact that you need units of work and to do queries from inside your domain classes implies that your model needs work.

Some other thoughts on UOW - having uow produce your repositories is good, but I think you will likely start hitting lots of difficulties with implementation. UoW is super useful in small targeted areas but is very difficult to implement across an entire application. What for example happens when you save? Can you never use EF directly? Is everything thread safe? You might want to simplify what you are trying to achieve.

In your example uow can be scoped to the HttpRequest. Many IoC containers (eg Structuremap) provide a simple way to configure this. You can then have a post-action filter (or even better an OWIN module) to attempt the commit (what happens if there are errors is yet another implementation difficulty to deal with). This will eliminate a lot of the property-assignment nonsense

I'm not sure what type of object is your `StoreFrontLogic`. It doesn't seem like a domain entity but it contains significant business logic. It could be something similar to a transaction script, but in that case the uow should be fully internal to it.

Is it a stateless service? In that case everything that method uses - orders for user included - should be passed in via a parameter.

If, on the other hand it's an entity then it shouldn't access the database at all, it should already have all orders for the user. Purposeful database denormalization can help quite a bit here.

At the very least pass uow as a parameter to `OffersForUser` rather than expecting for a property to be set.